# What's the relation between MariaDB and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I'm doing some research about **MariaDB** and **MySQL** for a project.
I know some differences between them, but is there a relation between the two of them?

*Like, is there any important things in common?
Will MariaDB replace MySQL soon or in the future?*

**How are they related?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing that cannot be found on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, originating from the time when Oracle bought Sun, shortly after Sun had bought MySQL AB. Because this did not sit well with Monty, one of the MySQL founders and lead developers, he forked MySQL and continued separately from then on.

Initially [advocating Sun was the near-perfect candidate for buying MySQL AB](http://monty-says.blogspot.ro/2008/01/sun-buys-mysql-ab.html), one of the reasons being Sun had no DB product of its own, the Sun-Oracle merger left him expressing [much more negative thoughts](http://monty-says.blogspot.ro/2009/12/oracle-gives-only-empty-promises-for.html).

What plans either companies have for each db, that is for them to know, but I think Monty is committed to [keeping MariaDB open-source](http://monty-says.blogspot.ro/2009/12/help-keep-internet-free.html) and on the same path MySQL was on before all the MySQL-Sun-Oracle business.

Comment: So basically MariaDB has been made with the same people behind MySQL because they were concerned about Oracle's interest of developing MySQL while they have another tool of their own, is that correct? is this how its related? then I can build my research upon this idea.

Comment: "I want to ensure that the MySQL code base (under the name of MariaDB) will survive as open source, in spite of what Oracle may do.” –– Michael “Monty” Widenius.

Comment: Added links to the answer

Comment: Thank you! that was helpful.